# Function PHP that check category post and change a part css of it (NO WORDPRESS)

Tags: php, css, function, colors, categories

I'm trying to find a function (PHP5 programming) that check the category of post and according to the result will change (in homepage) a part style (background-color) of it.

I don't know where start. Any suggestion ?

(I'M NOT USING WORDPRESS)

Thanks.

Comment: How are your categories organized?

Comment: kind of generic... more details are nedded

Comment: Is it possible that you are just searching the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS to acomplish that, just need to add a proper class to the post based on category

---

Anyway, heere's an example of something that changes background color according to category. You can use this as a starting point

**Mock up Post Class**

```
    class Post {
        public $text;
        public $category;
        public $style;

        public function __construct($text, $category) {
            $this->text = $text;
            $this->category = $category;
            $this->changeBg($category);
        }

        public function outputHTML() {
            return "<div class=\"category-{$this->category}\" style=\"{$this->style}\">{$this->text}</div>";
        }

        public function changeBg($category) {
            switch ($category) {
                case 'cat1':
                   $this->style = 'background-color: red';
                   break;
            }
        }

        public function __toSTring() {
            return $this->outputHTML();
        }
    }
```

**home page**

```
$post = new Post('this is a post blabla', 'cat1');
print $post;
```